# How can geoserver WFS service be configured to access only certain layers based on user role?

Tags: apache, tomcat, geoserver

We’re using geoserver 2.7.2 and having trouble setting up WFS security as needed.  Our intent is to publish a given workspace containing geoserver layers only to certain users.  I’ve read in the documentation that you can’t “combine” layer security and service security.  But we need *some* way of doing that even if it is custom code.  I’m hoping there might be users out there that would understand how to approach the problem technically, using filters etc. or other.

To be clear, we would like to setup rules whereby userA can access levels AA, AB.  And userB can access levels BA, BB for example.

I’ve setup security at the service level so only certain users have access to WFS and some have read-only access and some read/write access based on the user role.

Not surprisingly (given the documentation) if I setup layer security for a given feature type then that type can’t be accessed by WFS at all.  The feature does not show in the getCapabilities/catalog/other.

In case it matters our geoserver is deployed in tomcat which is accessed with a mod_jk mount on the back-end of apache web server.

Thanks in advance for any comments - Walter

Answer (score 1):

You can either write and plug-in your own [ResourceAccessManager](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/security/ResourceAccessManager.java) implementation, or use GeoFence (which provides an implementation of said interface, and a GUI and logic to drive what you want):
https://github.com/geoserver/geofence

Comment: Great response!  Thanks.  I didn't know about GeoFence.  It would appear to have just what I need.